# Using in IO monad, a function from other monad

Tags: haskell, monads

If I have a function like, in a monad T, `f1 :: T String`, and I want to use its outcome, print it, for example.

```
seeF1 :: IO String
seeF1 = do
  res <- f1
  print res
```

Why is it wrong?. It seems that I can't use f1 because it is not in the monad IO. So, How can I do it? lifting?

Comment: I think the answer to "How can I do it?" very much depends on what `T` is and what you are expecting to happen.

Answer (score 2):

In `do` notation, when you do

```
x = do
  y <- z
  ....
```

Then if `x :: (Monad m) => m a`, then `z :: (Monad m) => m b` were `m` is the same monad.

That is pretty logical after all : imagine if your `T` monad was list, what should your `seeF1` return? Or if your `T` monad was `Maybe`, `seeF1` wouldn't be able to print anything in case it encountered a `Nothing` since the result would be undefined.

Therefore in general, what you are asking for is not possible. But if you are a bit more specific about your `T`, then you might find a way to get an `IO a` from your `T a`. For instance if you look at the monads defined in [transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers), many have a `run` function that transform them, and from which you can get an `IO`.

Comment: I think your claim ("you need to define a lifting operation") is much too strong. Indeed, few monads have a sensible way to be "lifted" into `IO`. My guess is that the answer to the question is going to involve one of the `run*` family of functions -- but it's almost impossible to know until jonaprieto says a bit more about what he wants to do.